# Помогите экспортировать функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть функция jQuery, которая срабатывает при нажатии на клавишу. Как мне экспортировать и импортировать ее из другого файла в индексный файл проекта?
Помогите разобраться.

```
$('.addRow').click(function () {
  var ind = $('tr:last').index();
  $('.hide').clone().appendTo('table').addClass('row').removeClass('hide');
  $('tr:last>td:nth-child(2)>input').addClass('x');
  $('tr:last>td:nth-child(3)>input').addClass('y');
  $('tr:last>td:first').text(ind);
  data = [];
});
```

Comment: `data = [];` - ???

Comment: Прошу прощение, текст функции необходим лишь как пример того что я буду экспортировать, сам код не важен. Как мне экспортироваться эту функцию? Ведь у нее нет имени.

Comment: `function assign_addRowClick() { $('.addRow').click(function () { ... }); }`

Comment: что имеется ввиду под экспортированием и импортированием?

Comment: Имеется в виду что я хочу построить прект на js подобным образом как на React. Собственно говоря, когда я попытался вынести функцию срабатывающую по событию в отдельный файл, нашел проблему. Как мне экспортировать для начала содержимое файла, если функция анонимная? Да и как подключить его содержимое в индексный файл js, чтобы все по прежнему работало